# add 2 like button on same page <div id="fb-root"></div>

Tags: javascript, facebook

i need to add 2 like button on same page, i have got the javascript code and a div from facebook website since i need to add 2 of them they should have 2 different id, but in the javascript part i can't see fb-root, so i don't know if is possible to modify and how

this is the div with id **fb-root**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

i also try tried to add the same TAG twice and it doesn't work

i try to search on internet but coulden't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on 'Your Like Button plugin code:'

> Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once

You need to include the Javascript SDK only once. As you need to add two [like buttons](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) you can add

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<URL>" data-send="true"
 data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

and change the URL to the URL you would use to like.